# How to train a neural network to detect presence of a pattern?

Tags: neural-network, training-data

The question phrasing is vague - and I'm happy to change it based on feedback. But, I am trying to train a neural network to detect fraudulent transactions on a website. I have a lot of parameters as inputs (time of day, country of origin, number of visits in the past month, number of visits from unique IP's in the past month, number of transactions, average transaction size, etc, etc). Altogether, perhaps over 100 inputs. The inputs have been normalized and sanitized and they form a `time series`. Historically, I can look at my data and identify that a transaction was fraudulent of Type A or of Type B or not fraudulent. My training set can be large (in the thousands or tens of thousands of points).

Ultimately, I want an indicator: Fraud of Type A, Fraud of Type B or Not Fraud. Generally, fraudulent transactions tend to fit a pattern. I can't exactly identify the pattern (that's why I'm using a NN). However, not fraudulent transactions can be of any type of pattern. So it seems strange to identify things into 3 buckets when the third bucket is "other".

If this were a switch / case, it would be something like:

```
switch transactionData
  when transactionData.transaction_count < 0.2 && ....
    FRAUD_A
  when transactionData.transaction_count > 0.5 && ....
    FRAUD_B
  else
    NOT_FRAUD
```

Obviously, these are simplified cases, but my problem runs into how to properly train for the `else` case. Do I get three types of data (fraud_a, fraud_b and not_fraud) and train them? Or is there another way to train for `other`?

Comment: _"Do I get three types of data (fraud_a, fraud_b and not_fraud) and train them?"_ Based on my limited understanding of these things: yes.

Comment: The `not_fraud` however will have many different types of data patterns. Potentially, nothing that strings them together.

Comment: May sound unpleasant but I think you just need to start and see what happens. As of now, you seem to not have enough understanding of your data and the "else" class. Take your features and train them (or use some other analysis like clustering) in order to see the data for what it is. Only then you'll be able to identify possible subclasses within "else".

Comment: However, even if there are subclasses within `else`, I don't necessarily care. Not fraud is fine - I don't need to know in which way is it not fraud.

Comment: I am just starting out with ML, but if you use HMM over the data, data may be classified and then based on that you can predict Fraud or Not Fraud, Fraud can then further be divided into Type A or Type B. Please revert to make me understand more if you think HMM won't work. I wish to know why.

Comment: What is HMM? And how does one use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually perfectly ok to have OTHER (NOT FRAUD) class along with these you are interested in. But I understand your concern. Basically, its job of NN to learn "case/switch" and in most cases it will learn right one, assuming that most samples belong to NOT FRAUD class. In some pathological cases classifiers can learn different idea e.g. everything is FRAUD A class, unless proven otherwise. You can't usually control it directly, but it can be changed by creating better features and some other tricks. For now, proceed with what you have and see what happens.

One thing you can do is to train two classifiers, one (FRAUD/NOT FRAUD) and then if fraud is detected feed data into second two-class classifier (FRAUD A/FRAUD B). Sometimes (but not always) this works better.